# Entanglement island distance = quantum width of BH horizon?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement, stochastic-processes

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.03078) recent paper, Bousso and Penington (B&P) finds that the protrusion distance outside the horizon of an entanglement island from a 4D Schwarzschild black hole is $\sqrt {l_P r_{hor}}$, where $r_{hor}$ is the Schwarzschild radius of the BH and $l_p$ is the Planck length.

This result is a geometric mean, and is **exactly the same** length scale identified in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.01799) 2022 paper (e.g. Eqn 8) by Zurek, who applied a random walk argument to a BH horizon. Zurek called this a blurring of the horizon (a fuzzy, or uncertain horizon), and also went through some equivalent derivations, which basically supported the idea this length scale is the quantum uncertainty in the position of the BH horizon, aka a dynamic *quantum width* of an event horizon.

Perhaps it is the shifting position of the horizon that allows the entanglement island to protrude just that far, however, is the island truly "outside" if it cannot exceed the blur width?

**Question:** What is the conceptual bridge that makes these two results identical?

**EDIT**

**As requested in the comments, additional detail**. The main idea is the recent (circa 2019)

> emergence of a Page curve for an evaporating BH associated to
> entanglement entropy coming from an *island* behind the horizon.

You can find a Quanta article [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-most-famous-paradox-in-physics-nears-its-end-20201029/). Note the image, where the island is just *inside* the horizon.

Then, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11077) paper by AMA indicated the island could in fact, be *outside* the horizon.

Cue the B&P paper (a youtube presentation of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=irmUX1RrHM0), the main Eqn is found at 19.17 minutes, pop sci version [here](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/deep-space/a46331341/black-hole-islands/)), which concludes the island of a BH in 4D space-time can be up to $\sqrt {l_P r_{hor}}$ outside the horizon. And thus we can maybe resolve what actually happens at a BH horizon, experimentally.

What it would seem (to me anyhow), is that the whole *islands* idea means mathematically treating a BH as a shell. As soon as you do that, you will find, like Zurek, that the "shell thickness" is  $\sqrt {l_P r_{hor}}$, i.e. a quantum width. So does that still count as **outside**? *I think not, what do you think, dear reader?*.

Another point about trying to simplify this explanation is that the Quanta article maintains the long tradition of wrongly "explaining" BH evaporation via particle pair production. Although, when radiation comes out of a black hole, it should maintain a quantum mechanically entangled link to the interior of the black hole.

In [fact](https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/hawking-radiation-black-hole-evaporation/)

> the curved space around the black hole is constantly emitting
> radiation due to the curvature gradient around it, and the source of
> that energy is the black hole itself.

Comment: Can you provide more details about Bousso's paper? E.g. main ideas/assumptions/equations.